# Выполнение цикла в asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Можно ли в AsyncTask реализовать цикл, который будет повторяться либо какое-то количество раз, либо до того момента, когда пользователь нажмет кнопку "отмена" и если да, то где его нужно прописывать ? В doInBackGround или создавать для этого отдельный метод/класс ?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно можно. Вставляй свой цикл в `AsyncTask.doInBackground()`, далее там где надо остановиться вызывай `AsyncTask.cancel()` и проверяй значение `AsyncTask.isCancelled()` в своем цикле в `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` и если `true` - вылетай оттуда на фиг и все остановится.

Comment: Вылетать через break ?

Comment: бармелей так написал что мосх можно сломать =), наверно тебе достаточно по твоему условию вызывать AsyncTask.cancel() и все. Т.е. юзер на форме жмет ОТМЕНА - ты вызываешь AsyncTask.cancel(), метод AsyncTask.isCancelled() будет возвращать тру, если асинхТаск завершили раньше чем он отработает сам.

Comment: @Gorets, @alreadyexist - ну кто-то понял, а кто-то нет... Мне что еще и код вам написать с отловом всех возможных случаев, исключений? Я расписал общую схему, а дальше уж сами - это ваш хлеб, отрабатывайте!